# Using has_many :through with fields_for and checkboxes to create associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

That title's a mouthful.

So I have something like this:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_partner_associations
  has_many :partners, through: :company_partner_associations
end

class CompanyPartnerAssociation
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :partner
end

class Partner
  has_many :company_partner_associations
  has_many :companies, through: :company_partner_associations
end
```

And on a company form, i'm trying to make a list of all Partners with a checkbox next to them.  If I check one, it creates association.  If I uncheck it destroys.

```
<%= f.fields_for :company_partner_associations, Partner.all do |p| %>
    <%= f.check_box :partner_id %>
<% end %>
```

fails because the object getting passed is a Partner, so getting `undefined partner_id on Partner`

I'm sure there's a nifty solution out there!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :partner_ids, Partner.all, :id, :name %>
```

**No `fields_for`**.

This will have to be accompanied in the controller with the following params:

```
params.require(:company).permit(:company, :params, partner_ids: [])
```

This should set the `partner_ids` in your `@company` model.

With `HABTM`, you can declare associative data by populating the "`collection_singular_ids`" method; `HMT` has the same method appended with the [`has_many` relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

[image]

Although this will *replace* the current associated objects, it is much simpler than calling `f.fields_for` - especially for picking partners.

--

You can also use [`collection_check_boxes`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) which is meant for this purpose :)

Answer (score -1):

Not totally sure this is the problem here, but I think it could be that your controller is just not permitting the array of partner ids. So in your company_partner_params in your company controller needs to permit something like partner_attributes: [:id]. The syntax might not be perfectly correct there, but if that's something you're missing, you should look around for that.

This is what I think the form should look like:

```
<%= form_for @company do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :partners, Partner.all do |partner| %>
    ...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yeah it's not that it won't update, it errors on render.  `<%= p.check_box :partner_id %>` doesn't work because it's passing Partner as the object (from Partner.all) instead of the association.

Comment: My half baked solution was to build associations for each partner in the controller.  but seems like a rats nest when I'm sure some correct syntax would just make it happen

Comment: I haven't used this feature of rails much, but the syntax I've used was a bit different. I had the fields for block within a form_for block. Maybe try that.

Comment: I also think it's weird that you're calling the join table. I would have the @company in the form_for and :partners in the fields_for.

Comment: just an aside on my last edit, Partner.all shouldn't be done in the view. I think it would better done in a facade.

Comment: this isn't my pasted code, I'm just getting a point across.  So yes, I have a form_for block.  Passing a collection into it loops based on that, which is what I want, but it's not giving me the association

Comment: You tried using :partners instead of :company_partner_associations? I'm pretty sure my answer should work. If not, I'm out of ideas.